# Applying css to all paragraphs elements that overrides higher specifiers also

Tags: html, css, web, stylesheet

How can i apply CSS to all the paragraph elements of html document at once so that it also overrides higher specifiers also i know * selector but it select all element

```
 .about-box p{
        font-family: Montserrat-Regular;
        font-size: 14px;
        line-height: 16px;


    }
```

now if i apply following css it will not work on higher specifier like one given above

```
 p{

        font-size: 20px;

    }
```

i have tried using *P body>p .

Comment: add your html code too

Comment: @viira not needed?

Comment: @Arsii what about `!important`?

Comment: Simplest way, `p { font-size: 20px !important; }`

Comment: what do you mean by 'not needed?' @anderssonola

Comment: using !important is not the best idea try calling by its parent div's class name\

Comment: HTML is not needed to answer the question

Comment: using !important is bad idea . as i have to change font-size of all the paragraph elements of document

Comment: You can try `* > * > p, * > p { CSS rule.... }` Number of '*' depends on your higher specifiers.

Comment: @divy3993 i am refactoring a previously written css . so i don't know the level of hierarchies as per your approach

Comment: @Arsii Rasheed, Still it would work, just writing above line of code. Also you can still add up to 4 or more stars for safe side solution, I have added just up to 2 stars. Only exception case could be `!important`.

Comment: No your code is not working @divy3993. Have a look [here](https://jsfiddle.net/zxbvp7ha/).

Comment: for those recommending !important ..remember i am refactoring previously written css that is very badly written . using !important again again for different properties is bad choice

Comment: If you have badly written CSS, throw it away and start again. Trying to override the badly written CSS will just result in even more badly written CSS.

Comment: You can only overwrite higher specifiers with even higher ones. You'll have to work component by component. If there are separate components, I'd recommend splitting your css in logically separated chunks.

Comment: @Huelfe & @Arsii Rasheed It would work, you will have to tweak a little with selectors like `class`, `id`. It is the only way as your requirement is to satisfy any condition. Posting an answer for same in a minute.

Comment: @ArsiiRasheed, was not able to post answer sooner, was busy a little today. If you are still looking for a solution, posted an answer. Hope it might help you out. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*It takes a thief to catch a thief.*

There might not be the right way to correct the wrong. But following could help you to solve or achieve what you want.

What you need is help of `class` and `id` selectors, to act as the higher specifiers so that they would override other higher specifiers.

## Solution:

```css
html [class] > p, 
html * > * > p,
html [class] > * > p,
html [id] > * > p,
html [class] > * > * > p,
html [id] > * > * > p {
    font-size: 20px;
}

.about-box p {
    font-family: Montserrat-Regular;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="about-box">
        <h2>About Us</h2>
        <p>some paragraph goes here ....</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <div class="caption">
                <h2 class="text-center">Your Books & Book Proposals:</h2>
                <p>paragraph goes here </p>
                <p>paragraph here</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

@huelfe Thanks for the jsFiddle code, used your HTML.

Also sharing [Codepen](https://codepen.io/divy3993/pen/vaoRwa) to tweak the code and play around.

Comment: You have the same problem like me as ChanMT described under my answer. This answer will not work, if your css is defined before `.about-box p`.

Comment: @Huelfe, Updated answer you can verify it.

Comment: Or you just use `html [class] p, html [id] p {}`. The other selectors are not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of doing this. Either you use `!important`:

```css
.about-box p {
  font-family: Montserrat-Regular;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 16px;
}

p {
  font-size: 20px !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="about-box">
  <p>
    test
  </p>
</div>
<p>
  test2
</p>
```

Or you set an id on a higher level element like body:

```css
#body p {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.about-box p {
  font-family: Montserrat-Regular;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 16px;
}
```

```html
<body id="body">
  <div class="about-box">
    <p>
      test
    </p>
  </div>
  <p>
    test2
  </p>
</body>
```

Comment: Do note that although the “parent class selector” in your answer appears to be working, it is not due to `.body` is the parent of the `.about-box`, but because its CSS defined **after** the `.about-box`. Try to reverse the order of the CSS and you'll see that it fails to work. CSS doesn't care about element hierarchy when it comes to determining which style to follow. `.about-box p` and `.body p` have the same specificity, so the latter will take effect.

Comment: You are right. In this case he could use a selector with an id for the parent. I will edit this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand how [CSS cascading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Cascade_and_inheritance) works, and in this case, the how Specificity works. `.about-box p` is more specific than plain `p`, hence you can never override the style defined in `.about-box p` with `p` alone, unless you want to use the dreaded `!important` syntax (which is usually a bad idea).

It seems to me that you want to override the `font-size` defined in `.about-box p`. If so, why not modify/remove it directly? If you can't, you can also do this:

```
.about-box p{
    font-family: Montserrat-Regular;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 16px;
}

p, .about-box p {
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

Edit: Based on your comment, this sounded like another case of "this is not my code I'm just trying to fix this one thing". I'd still strongly suggest you to do a search and remove all `font-size` defined for `p` in your CSS.

There is just no way that a CSS definition can override a higher specifiers without being the same level or even higher itself (unless by importance). Now the thing is we're unable to see if you only have this one class to override, or there are many more that you didn't mention. There is no way we can give any valuable suggestions if we cannot see the full picture.

Without a doubt, the `!important` is the fastest solution, but almost always a bad one too.

Comment: i want to change font-size of all the paragraphs in document not single higher specfer

Answer (score 0):

Check out my code,

```css
.about-box p {
  font-family: Montserrat-Regular;
  line-height: 16px;
}        
p {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="about-box">
  <p>Paragraph 1</p>
</div>
<p>Paragraph 2</p>
```

Comment: Oh, Just now i saw it.

Comment: @Arsii Rasheed i have made change